# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 using mpirun in local (no reomte X connections)

Tags: cookie

When I run a mpirun comand in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I get the error
*Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key*

I tried different procedures found in the forums and I also reinstalled my invidia drivers. Nothing worked.
The problem is in the local system, I'm not using ssh connections and I do not have a .Xauthority file.

For example if I run:
/usr/bin/mpirun -n 1 echo "HelloWorld"

I get:
*Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyHelloWorld*

This is annoying because when I want to redirect the output on a file I have this message in every row of a mpi comand.

How can I solve this?
Thanks,
Nabla

Comment: ... you don't have a `.Xauthority` file - is that because you are running a Wayland session?

Comment: I don't know wayland.. How can I check if it is active..?

Comment: Not sure tbh... try the answers here [How to know whether Wayland or X11 is being used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202891/how-to-know-whether-wayland-or-x11-is-being-used)

Comment: Ok, if I enter:  "$ loginctl show-session 2 -p Type  "     I get:                                           
Type=x11

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @ManuelOliveira for me: check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659362/how-to-generate-correctly-a-new-xauthority-file-for-a-display-missing-it-witho. Newest installations of debian make as default easy as hostname for whatever reasons. this created a lot problems for me. check sysctl.conf, set kernel.hostname=NAME, and populate changes in bashrc adding `sysctl -p --system`. Also, `cat .Xauthority` to check what is the hostname given there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has been answered yet. But I solved this problem by uninstalling mpich with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mpich
```

and reinstalling it with

```
sudo apt install mpich
```